# How to access order data on Big Commerce on confirmation screen

Tags: bigcommerce

I need to add some JavaScript to the order confirmation page that includes details about the order. Although I can access the order id through a BigCommerce global variable, I cannot work out how to get the rest of the order details into my JavaScript.

For instance, I can access the BigCommerce order_id global `%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%` and use that in a JavaScript alert, but I also need to access the following:

1. order total
2. order tax
3. order shipping
4. order postcode

And foreach product in the order

1. product_id
2. unit_price
3. quantity

There these global items but when I try to access them they are blank, I presume that I need to loop through the cart contents.

1. %%GLOBAL_ProductModel%%
2. %%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%
3. %%GLOBAL_ProductQty%%

I have read all the docs I can find. Can anyone give me an idea of how to achieve this. I need the values so I can pass them to a third party JS function for their use. All of that is waiting and ready but I cannot get the data out of Big Commerce templating system. The data is there, on the order.html template page, as the social sharing panel reads it, but again I cannot see how the social sharing snippet is accessing it.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do a Google Trusted Store integration or something similar. The Order ID is available to be scraped from the page, but there is no exposure of the product contents data. There might be a lack of documentation to due an absence of answer :p

Comment: It is actually a getsidecar.com integration and I have all their js on the required pages, all the accounts are ready to roll. But I have no idea how to do this final element. They cannot tell me, Big Commerce cannot tell me or seem to not want to tell me. I am a PHP develolper but have never seen such a closed system as BC seem to run. It seems like you do it with the data they provide for the page or good luck to you. They have been so unhelpful. Modifying the HTML templates is a breeze, but getting data onto the page is seemingly impossible - or I am ignorant of how to do it.

Comment: You can get variables if you enabled the google trusted store integration (depending on what plan you are on) or you can use the scraped order ID to build an api request that you sent to a 3rd party server and fetch results for the remaining variables. Requests and return will require AJAX

Comment: The bounty was added as a thank you for a great answer below. I am not sure I did this correctly but just to let everyone know that it is for a thank you to root who's answer was so helpful to me, thank you again to 'root' but I have to wait 24 hours to award it (which seems a bit daft as clearly it is a retrospective thank you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a hacky script just for you that pulls the product data (as well as some order details).

It parses the data from the `%%GLOBAL_ConversionCode%%` template variable, and as such this script should be inserted in `order.html` immediately after the `%%GLOBAL_ConversionCode%%` variable.

Specifically,  `%%GLOBAL_ConversionCode%%` outputs to:

```js
<!-- Include the conversion tracking code for all analytics packages -->
<!-- Start conversion code for analytics_googleanalytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(typeof(pageTracker) != 'undefined') {
    pageTracker._addTrans(
      '196',
      'store-name',
      '0.00',
      '2.12',
      '1.92',
      'Austin',
      'Texas',
      'United States'
    );

    pageTracker._addItem(
      '196',
      '2004',
      'TAKE YOUR TIME: Sweet Body Butter',
      '',
      '24.96',
      '1'
    );

    pageTracker._trackTrans();
  }
</script>
```

---

Solution:

```js
<script>
    //-------------- Main --------------//

    //** Create the order data array from analytics script **//
    var data = parseAnalyticsData(getAnalyticsScript());
    //console.log(data);

    /**
     * Retrieve the order details as an object, properties are:
     * id          - The order ID.
     * shipping    - The order shipping cost. 
     * tax         - The order tax cost. 
     * shippingTax - The order shipping tax cost.
     * city        - The order shipping city.
     * state       - The order shipping state. 
     * country     - The order shipping country.
     */
    var orderDetails = getOrderDetails(data);

    console.log("Order ID = %d", orderDetails.id);
    console.log("Order shipping city = %s", orderDetails.city);
    console.log("Order subtotal = %f", orderDetails.subtotal);

    /**
     * Retrieve the order product details, as an array of product objects. 
     * Properties are:
     * id          - The product ID. 
     * description - The product description.
     * tax         - The product tax cost.
     * price       - The product price per product. 
     * qty         - The product quantity purchased. 
     */
    var products = getOrderProducts(data);

    //** Loop through the products array to access each product **//
    console.log("Total number of products = %d", products.length);
    for (x=0; x<products.length; x++) {
      console.log("--------");
      console.log("Item # ", x+1);
      console.log("Product ID = %f", products[x].id);
      console.log("Product QTY = %f", products[x].qty);
      console.log("Product Price = %f", products[x].price);
      console.log("--------");
    }



    //-------------- Functions --------------//

    /**
     * Parses the DOM to retrieve the order data analytics script.
     */
    function getAnalyticsScript() {
      var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
      var thisScriptTag = scripts[scripts.length - 2];
      var data = thisScriptTag.textContent || thisScriptTag.innerText;
      return data;
    }

    /**
     * Parses the raw analytics script element to remove all script
     * text, and parse just the order related data into an array.
     * @param script <String> - The raw order analytics script.
     * @return <mixed> - Array containing the order data. 
     */
    function parseAnalyticsData(data) {
      String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
        var target = this;
        return target.split(search).join(replacement);
      };
      // This is hacky, and probably inefficient, but it removes all
      // script related text, so the end result is just a comma separated
      // array of the order and product data. 
      data = data.replace("if(typeof(pageTracker) != 'undefined') {", '');
      data = data.replaceAll( 'pageTracker._addTrans(', '');
      data = data.replaceAll( ' pageTracker._trackTrans();', '');
      data = data.replaceAll( 'pageTracker._addItem(', '');
      data = data.replaceAll(');', '');
      data = data.replace('}', '');
      data = data.replace( /\n/g, ",").replaceAll( ",,",",");
      data = data.replace(/\s/g,'');
      data = data.split(',');
      data = cleanArray(data); // Remove all empty values from array. 
      return data;
    }

    /**
     * Removes all empty data from array.
     * @param array <mixed> - The array to clean. 
     */
    function cleanArray(array) {
      var newArray = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i]) {
          newArray.push(array[i]);
        }
      }
      return newArray;
    }

    /**
     * Parse Analytics Data for Order Details
     * @param data <mixed> - The order analytics data.
     * @return <mixed>     - Object containing the order details. 
     */
    function getOrderDetails(data) {
      String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
        var target = this;
        return target.split(search).join(replacement);
      };
      return {
        id          : parseFloat(data[0].replaceAll("'",'')),
        subtotal    : ( parseFloat(data[2].replaceAll("'",'')) - (parseFloat(data[3].replaceAll("'",'')) + parseFloat(data[4].replaceAll("'",'')) ) ),
        total       : parseFloat(data[2].replaceAll("'",'')),
        tax         : parseFloat(data[3].replaceAll("'",'')),
        shipping    : parseFloat(data[4].replaceAll("'",'')),
        city        : data[5].replaceAll("'",''),
        state       : data[6].replaceAll("'",''),
        country     : data[7].replaceAll("'",'')
      }
    }

    /**
     * Parse Analytics Data for All Order Product Details.
     * @param data <mixed> - The order analytics data.
     * @return <mixed>     - Array containing individual product details.
     */
    function getOrderProducts(data) {
      String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
        var target = this;
        return target.split(search).join(replacement);
      };
      var counter = -1;        // Keep index of details per product.
      var productsArray = []; // Init empty array to hold all products. 
      var product = {};       // Init empty object to hold single product data. 
      //** Product data starts at index 8 **//
      for (x=8; x<data.length; x++) {
        counter++;
        switch (counter) {
          case 1:
            product.id = parseFloat(data[x].replaceAll("'",''));
            break;
          case 2:
            product.description = data[x].replaceAll("'",'');
            break;
          case 3:
            product.tax = parseFloat(data[x].replaceAll("'",''));
            break;
          case 4:
            product.price = parseFloat(data[x].replaceAll("'",''));
            break;
          case 5:
            product.qty = parseFloat(data[x].replaceAll("'",''));
            counter = -1;                 // reset counter
            productsArray.push(product); // push product to products array
            product = {};
            break;
        }
      }
      return productsArray;
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: Wow, you are a superstar. I will try it out first thing tomorrow and let you know, but thanks, that looks amazing :-)

Comment: Thank you Sire! Let me know if everything makes sense, and if accessing the data is clear (via the `orderDetails` & `products` objects).

Comment: In the end I found another way to access the data, but your solution gave me the clue about interrogating the analytic code. I repeat that you are a superstar - thank you for this info, it genuinely helped.

Comment: I started a bounty to give you +50 as a thanks, but I cannot award it just yet. But rest assured it is on it's way. Thank you again!